# Is it possible to monitor other application using Cocoa on Mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

For example, get the notification that another Application is becoming Active on the screen, or resign active state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In OS X, how can I detect when the currently active application changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204243/in-os-x-how-can-i-detect-when-the-currently-active-application-changes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure. In your app delegate class, you can use `NSWorkspace` to get notified when an app becomes active ([`NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-SW97)) or resigns active ([`NSWorkspaceDidDeactivateApplicationNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-SW98)). See the documentation on [`NSWorkspace`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.

In your controller class, you'd do something like this:

```
- (id)init {
   if ((self = [super init])) {
       [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self
                             selector:@selector(appDidActivate:)
                            name:NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification
                              object:nil];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)appDidActivate:(NSNotification *)notification {
   NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
   NSLog(@"userInfo == %@", userInfo);

}
```

The key points are basically that you need to register to receive the notifications like shown in `-init`. You'd repeat the code to add another observer for each additional notification name that you want (e.g `NSWorkspaceDidDeactivateApplicationNotification`).

Another important thing to remember is to remove yourself as an observer in `-dealloc` (or elsewhere), so that `NSWorkspace` doesn't try to notify your controller object after it's been released+dealloc'd (and would no longer be valid).

In the specified `-appDidActivate:` method, do whatever you need to with the info about the app in question.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for `NSWorkspace` in ios simulator SDK?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something simpler than [distributed objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/DistrObjects.html), you could use distributed notifications from the distributed notification center. However, these are not posted unless you built the application. For monitoring when applications start or quit, you can use NSWorkspace and its notification center (suggested by NSGod)